# Laravel route limit throttle remaining not work

Tags: laravel, routes, limit, middleware, throttling

I set limits on each route independently, but the "count" is not done correctly. For example, these requests are the first ones that have been executed (and only once each): Why the count is not done correctly? A limit of 60 can be exceeded in only 16/17 requests (example)

(network inspector)

```
route 1
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 56

Route 2
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 57

Route 3
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 55

Route 4
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 56


Route 5
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 55

Route 6
X-RateLimit-Limit: 20
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 14
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('myRoute1', 'Controller@method')->middleware('throttle:60,1');
Route::get('myRoute2', 'Controller@method')->middleware('throttle:60,1');
Route::get('myRoute3', 'Controller@method')->middleware('throttle:60,1');
Route::get('myRoute4', 'Controller@method')->middleware('throttle:60,1');
Route::get('myRoute5', 'Controller@method')->middleware('throttle:60,1');
Route::get('myRoute6', 'Controller@method')->middleware('throttle:20,1');
```

the first 5 requests were made while loading the same page. The last one was called by going to another page

Comment: The rate limiting is not specific to a single route, it is enforced across all routes instead.

Comment: @PtrTon So I can not do it ?

Comment: The default laravel middleware does not support it, however other packages might do so. After looking around a bit I found [this snippet](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22929#issuecomment-463282531) extending the default throttle middleware with a group identifier. Maybe that's useful to you.